# Wordpress Plugin Custom Databse Query (SQL UPDATE SET WHERE)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

**Quick background:**

- CRUD plugin
- WP 3.5
- Creating this plugin for my personal knowledge - I'm sure one already exists.
- Variables echo out ok.
- The create portion of plugin needed 3 hours of research to get the query to work. Tried everything in codex, a handful of answers from Stack Overflow until something worked.

**Problem:**

- Updating a row in a custom table.
- This query will work in SQL ->

  UPDATE wp_current_issue SET issue_year=9999, issue_month=29 WHERE issue_id=17;

**Tried:**

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update(CURRENT_ISSUE_TABLE, 
        array(
            'issue_year' => $issue_year,
            'issue_month' => $issue_month
            ),
        array('issue_id' => $issue_edit_id),
        array('%d','%d'),
        array('%d'));
```

As well as: (with and without backticks around column names)

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_current_issue SET issue_year=".$issue_year.", issue_month=".$issue_month." WHERE issue_id=".$issue_edit_id);

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Now the funny thing is, I went through the same thing with the INSERT INTO statement. Tried everything. Only thing that would work is this:

```
        global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO `".CURRENT_ISSUE_TABLE."` (`issue_path`,`issue_img_path`,`issue_year`,`issue_month`) VALUES (%s,%s,%d,%d)", $fileName_issue, $fileName_img, $issue_year, $issue_month);

    $wpdb->query($sql);
```

Anyone know how I could rewrite this query for an update statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your problem correctly if you want to rewrite that insert into an update then just use

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
"UPDATE `".CURRENT_ISSUE_TABLE."` SET `issue_path` = %s, `issue_img_path` = %s, `issue_year` = %s, `issue_month` = %s
    WHERE issue_id = %i", $fileName_issue, $fileName_img, $issue_year, $issue_month, $issue_edit_id);
```

The rest is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice on that query. But I did learn something important -> the integer variable... %i. How did I not know that? Thanks for a quick reply man.

Comment: This absolutely worked. Please forgive my earlier dismissal of your response. It was a form problem all along; I left a blank action on it. Rookie stuff. I faced that problem earlier and immediately thought it was wordpress query syntax. Thank you again sir!